# How to choose the right solver for thermo-fluid system modeling in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am working on a large thermo-fluid model in Dymola, but when using the default solver(Dassl), the model couldn't converge because it shows the model is stiff. So I try to use another solver, it turns out only one of them (Esdirk45a) works fine.

[image]

Here is the recommendation from  Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory's building library ([here is the link](https://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/modelica/userGuide/bestPractice.html)), but this solver doesn't work in my case.

[image]

My question is:
1. What is the difference between different solvers?
2. How should I choose the right solver for different models?

Comment: Just searching Google for "[Dassl Radau Esdirk](https://www.google.com/search?q=dassl+radau+esdirk)" returns several interesting results, e.g. this one: https://www.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Professoren/FreyG/LL_FF_GF_ETFA2010_sept_2010.pdf

Comment: have you tried to provide nominal values for e.g. pressures and enthalpies as well as mass flows? The high differences in orders of magnitude are difficult to handle for solvers. What kind of error messages do you get when using Radau and Dassl?

Comment: Having only a single solver that is working is a strong indication, that the model itself is very, very critical. A model should be solvable with various different solvers which all provide similar results (potentially with very different performance).
I would suggest to try fixing the model instead picking a solver that (by luck) works with a problematic model.

Comment: @ImkeKrueger, When using Dassl and Radau, it shows the model is stiff, and it takes a long time during initialization. In fact, because it takes so long that I have never waited until the initialization finished.

Comment: @Marvel what did you try  to improve your initial equations and values?Do you provide decreasing pressures along the flow path to ensure a mass flow direction? You could try to find pressure levels that work and use then ramps to reach the desired values. are there maybe two flow models connected without a volume model inbetween?

Comment: Dassault has published a whitepaper regarding initialization problems and analysis: https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Debugging_Initialization_in_Dymola_2019.pdf

Comment: You can tell Dymola to store variables even if the integrator step fails. This will give you access (plotting) to variables that caused the initialization to fail. Note however that the results at the last output point are inconsistent; some variables were calculated before the failure and some were not.